# Declare variables for the number and the total

Tags: python

```
# Declare variables for the number, and the
# total.

def main():
# Initialize for while loop
    number = 1.0
    total = 0.0

# Continue adding numbers while they are positive.
while number > 0:
    number = float(input('Enter a positive number' \ ' (negative to quit): '))

    # Check that number is positive so as
    # not to change value of the total.
    if number > 0:
        total != total + number
    if number > 0:
        total == total + number

# Display total.
print ('Total =', format.(total, '.2f'))

main()
```

everytime I run it says 'unexpected character after line continuation character'

what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Why didn't you put the `/` in quotes to?

Comment: Fix you assignments to `total` too. `total != total + number` and `total == total + number` are just boolean operations that will return true or false, but will not change the value stored in `total`. It's effectively a no-op. If you actually intended to do a comparison, you should know that it's probably not going to work. Google "python floating point equality" for more info. You also have the same conditional expression twice. Was one a typo?

Comment: Your main function doesn't get called until after the `while` loop executes, and the variables it initializes are local to it anyway, not the global variables used by the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
number = float(input('Enter a positive number' \ ' (negative to quit): '))
```

Perhaps to this:

```
number = float(input('Enter a positive number (negative to quit): '))
```

Everything that's part of `main()` should be indented consistently (e.g. with 4 spaces).

Also, change this line:

```
total == total + number
```

To this:

```
total = total + number
```

Comment: I'd say he wanted something like this: `'Enter a positive number\(negative to quit): '` With the backslash in double quotes as well. That's really the only reason I could see him using a backslash where he did.

Comment: Or: `number = float(input('Enter a positive number\n(negative to quit): '))`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/computer program/last assignment/assignment2.py", line 26, in <module>
    print ('Total =', format(total, '.2f'))
NameError: name 'total' is not defined
>>>

Comment: it keeps saying that I am some how not defining it

Comment: I updated my answer. See also the comments above to your original question - they are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When you type:

```
number = float(input('Enter a positive number' \ ' (negative to quit): '))
```

The backslash is automatically read as a line continuation character, which python expects to be followed by n for newline.